# calling a list of functions in a particular order?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd rather do this

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self._TESTS = {
            'val1': self.test1,
            #...
            'val10': self.test10
        }
    def test(self, x):
        for v, f in self._TESTS.items():
            if f(x):
                return v
        return None
```

over this

```
class A:
    def test(self, x):
        if self.test1(x):
            return 'val1'
        #...
        if self.test10(x):
            return 'val10'
        return None
```

However I need to call the `test*` methods in a particular order. How would you do this?

I could use `collections.OrderedDict`, but actually I don't a dictionary at all as I call all the test at once always. So, a list of tuples perhaps?

Comment: How many test methods could you have?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ surprisingly, 10 :) I though I I had actually less, but counted them after you asked :)

Comment: Aha. I asked out of pure curiosity. Was wondering what kind of problems could warrant such interesting functional models.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ just seems cleaner to me, even if I had 3-4

Answer (score 2):

yes, works with a list of `tuples`, order preserved, no need for dict since no need for lookup. The loop is just slightly different, no more `.items()` but direct unpacking:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self._TESTS = [
            ('val1', self.test1),
            #...
            ('val10', self.test10)
        ]
    def test(self, x):
        for v, f in self._TESTS:
            if f(x):
                return v
        return None
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use a `list` of `tuples`, like this:

```
self._TESTS =[("v1", self.test1), ...]
```

Answer (score 1):

If your test functions placed in arbitrary order - use a sorted list of tuples:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self._TESTS = [
            (2, 'val10', self.test10),
            ...
            (1, 'val1', self.test1),
            #...                
        ]

    def test(self, x):
        for t in sorted(self._TESTS):
            if t[2](x):
                return t[1]
        return None
```

Comment: I could write the `_TEST` in the order I need upfront, can't I? Could be good for dynamic ordering though

Answer (score 1):

I do not quite understand the question as you already provide a possible answer which would quite certainly work.
The full answer is: it depends. If it is important that you still keep your Test dictionary around, to have some kind of external access to it, then you should just specify the sequence of execution in your `test(self, x)` method:

```
class A:
def __init__(self):
    self._TESTS = {
        'val1': self.test1,
        #...
        'val10': self.test10
    }
def test(self, x):
    my_test_sequence = ['val10', 'val1']
    for v in my_test_sequence:
        if self._TESTS[v](x):
            return v
    return None
def test1(self, arg):
    return True
def test10(self, arg):
    return True

A().test(1) #val10
```

Comment: thanks. Just wanted to check if there are some more recommended techniques and best practices